# Does MicroUSB B have 5 separate wires?

Tags: usb, connector, wiring, usb-device

I am working on a project that requires a 5 pin connector but it seems like the USB cable is causing some issues. I am using a microUSB B male-male cord to transfer some power and data. Through further research, I am seeing that Micro USB B may be more complex than a simple 5 wire cord. I found the following quote online:

"Contrary to popular belief, D+ and D- operate together; they are not separate simplex connections."

http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/micro_usb_pinout.shtml

What does this mean? Is there a way I can use this cable as 5 separate connections?

Comment: Usually, the 5th pin on Micro USB is to support [USB OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go). This 5th pin is usually grounded at one end of the cable to arbitrate master/slave roles for data transfer between two USB devices. If you're repurposing a USB cable as a general 5-pin cable, I'd check to make sure that pin isn't internally grounded at one end.

Comment: The Simplex comment means that when in use, the lines are used as one differential pair - the PC talks to the device, the device talks back, similar to sending/receiving over RS485. Vs RS232, where each side sends on wire and receives on the other.

Comment: you can use the cable as 5 separate wires ..... `D+ and D- operate together` .... in USB application the two lines are used to transmit a single data signal .... that "joining" is done in the circuitry outside of the cable ..... in the cable itself, the two wires are still electrically separate, so you could use them separately for other applications that do not involve USB

Answer (score 6):

You should expect 4 wires in the cable. Ground and the shield will be connected together at one (possibly both) ends. The 5th ID pin is there to tell you what sort of cable it is. The only male to male cables in the standard are OTG cables which will have ID open circuit at one end and connected to ground at the other.

Comment: I see thank you for the info. Are the connections you speak of internal in the cable or usually on the board that the cable is connected to? Would it be possible for me to connect the ID to shield and use that as an analog line? or is that bad practice?

Comment: the connections are made in the cable, they indicate to the device the cable is connected to, what sort of cable it is. The cable will either connect ID to ground and the shield, or leave it unconnected. So yes you could use the connected together ground-id-shield as a signal line, but you'd need to use something else for ground, and as soon as someone accidentally plugs your device into a PC, bad things will happen.

Answer (score 3):

Few points to consider:

1. There is no micro-USB B male-male cords, officially. There are micro-B to micro-A male-male cords. Male-male cords of A-A or B-B type are USB-illegal, and whoever makes and uses these cords are doing a disservice to USB community.
2. Micro-A-B cables have only 4 signal wires.The ID pin is never implemented within standard cable and is not connected between the ends. The only exception are proprietary short cables for test equipment like "Packet-Master USB-PET Protocol and Electrical Tester".
3. In a micro-B to micro-A male-male cord the B-end has ID pin unconnected; the A-end has ID pin grounded. The grounding is done locally, in the overmold. This signaling is invented for devices that can act in dual-data role, as devices and as hosts, formerly known as "OTG". These devices are supposed to have so-called micro-A-B receptacle, which can accommodate both B and A plugs. The ID pin informs the device which role it is supposed to assume.

So, no, you can't use any micro USB connectors as a 5-wire interface, there are only 4 wires that propagate from one end to another.

FINALLY: you cannot use USB2 cables even for four simplex connections, because the D+/D- are made of twisted pair of wires, so they are tightly coupled. Any attempt to transmit independent (like CLK and DATA) relatively high frequency (fast edge) signals will result in strong cross-talk and signal distortions, up to double-clocking or false data states.

Comment: "These devices are supposed to " but usually don't :( so sadly cables with a micro B connector on the "host end" are needed in practice.

Answer (score 3):

I thought the ID pin was pin 4 not 5. Pin 5 is ground.
[picture showing pin4 as id and pin5 as ground]

pinouts From another source with pin 4 as id
[image]

Answer (score 3):

USB 1/2 has four wires, Ground, Power and a differential pair for communications.

Mini and micro connectors add a fifth pin, "OTG-ID", the way this was supposed to work is that devices that only support device mode have a "B" socket while devices that support both modes would have an "AB" socket. Cables would have an A connector on the host end and a B connector on the device end. Devices with AB sockets would detect whether they had an A or B connector plugged in by how the OTG_ID pin was connected, at the A end it's tied to ground, at the B end it's left floating. The cable still only has 4 wires.

Unfortunately the phone/tablet industry screwed this up. Many phones/tablets support host mode, but are fitted with a micro B connector rather than a micro AB connector. This in turn means that OTG cables and adapters have to be produced with micro B connectors on the host end.

Answer (score 0):

*(Caveat emptor: This answer is for people who're looking for a working solution to making a Micro-USB type B double-ended male cable, despite it directly contravening the standard. I wanted it to use my Pi Zero 2 W as the host for my Pi Pico Dev environment)*

Before I found this question and the other answers, I had already ordered a set of [4-contact micro-USB type B male connectors](https://evelta.com/usb-2-0-micro-b-male-usb-connector-smd-4pin-u251-041n-4bsg86/) in my ignorance.

Looking at the available male connectors on component sellers like [digikey](https://www.digikey.in/en/products/filter/usb-dvi-hdmi-connectors/usb-dvi-hdmi-connector-assemblies/312?s=N4IgjCBcoEwBxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALGHFTCALqEAOALlCAMosBOAlgHYBzEAF9CMAJyIQKSBhwFiZEAGY4AdjgAGLQ2ZtInHgOFiQAWjrQZUHgFdFJSOQCsDER6A), [mouser](https://www.mouser.com/c/connectors/usb-connectors/?gender=Plug%20%28Male%29&product=Micro%20USB%20Type%20B%20Connectors) or [lcsc](https://www.lcsc.com/products/USB-Connectors_369.html), I found that connectors are available with both 4-contact and 5-contact variants. After reading the other answers, and then digging into the details, I discovered that the 4-contact variants have Pin-4 as NC internally, while the 5-connector variants are where Pin-4 can be grounded or left NC as per requirements while soldering.

However, knowing that the Pi Zero 2 worked as host by default, I skipped on ordering a 5-contact, and just used the 4 contact variants that I had.

Soldering the 4 pin connectors with 2 inch long wires (scavenged from multi-core DuPont connectors), such that the pins were correctly aligned (i.e. if the cable is bent into a U-shape, both the plugs are in the same orientation) gives a cable that "just works" to connect the Pi Pico to the Pi Zero 2.

The inside of the pudding:
[image: Zero 2W to Pico]